# House wide 24v dc on single extra conductor?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v

Is it feasible to provide a house wide 24v DC supply that uses mains neutral or ground for the -ve side?

Edit: I removed reference to "NEUTRAL OR ground" because risks, and RCDs, per answers.

Where I am AC is 230v, and and 3-core TPS is normal.  If I could get a single 24v  at each power outlet, then I can put fairly cheap USB-C Power Delivery points for 5v to 20v DC at each outlet.

But can i use 4-core single phase for this, or do I need to use a separate DC pair?  Are there risks beyond the obvious ones (like accidentally bridging the 24v +DC and AC live!)?

Comment: Mains neutral?? You know, neutral wires are insulated *for a reason*...

Comment: any exposed metal with a DC voltage will corrode on the positive end, like a car battery. You also have to worry a lot more about voltage drop at 24v than 230v; losses which could very well exceed the inefficiency of a name-brand AC-DC USB adapter, which these days can be 95% efficient. Unless you have many many points of need _and_ your electric co charges for _apparent power_ (w/ smart meter), point-of-use conversion is best.

Comment: @dandavis Yup, I've done voltage loss calculations.  The cost for the at-outlet complete 80W USB-C PD module taking 24v is under USD $3, whereas a no-brand full USB-C PD incl power supply is about $15.

Comment: @Monica.  Yes, yes I do.  Do you?

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you can't mix high voltage (120, 240 and above) with low voltage (definition varies, but 24V is definitely low voltage). This means you can't use part of a high voltage *cable* for low voltage DC, and it also means you can't mix and match low & high voltage individual wires in conduit.

Part of this is the obvious "accidentally bridging the 24v +DC and AC live" safety problem, and there are other reasons as well.

As far as the specific question of neutral or ground as the other 1/2 of the circuit. **No, you can't do that.** Along with any other safety issues, the wires have fundamentally different uses:

- "Ground" in DC circuits refers to a return path for the circuit. The "ground wire" in a mains AC circuit (the green or bare wire) is not normally used to carry current, except during a fault situation. Loading it up with 24V DC is therefore not a good idea.
- Neutral in AC circuits is *logically* like ground in DC circuits, but it actually carries just as much current *and the AC variation thereof*. So some of the time that DC current would (theoretically) be opposite the AC current in the neutral (i.e., bringing it closer to 0) and some of the time it would be in the same direction (more current than normal). In any case, it won't work and it isn't allowed.

Comment: Well said! Hopefully the OP gets the message how badly conceived their query really is.

Comment: But they asked! That's the key - ask first. Much better than "I tried this and now I wonder if it is OK".

Comment: I know! But you answer provides the strong statement to not even consider the scheme proposed.

Comment: TL;DR: **_NO_** You cannot mix AC and DC on a single wire even if that wire has the same "name" in each of the two, incompatible, electrical systems.

Comment: There's a third reason if the AC circuit has a GFCI: returning any current on the neutral that didn't originate from the paired hot will trip the GFCI.

Comment: Neutral is part of the normal-active AC mains loop, so using it as part of the LV loop would be insane.  Any glitch in the neutral (these happen all the time) would energize all the LV stuff at 230V.

Comment: So, for everyone saying you "just can't" mix AC and DV on the same cable because they are electrically different, just wow.  Google DC Bias.  For those pointing out reasons why neutral is risky, or problematic, thanks, these largely coincide with my assumptions.  I'm still not seeing any reason to not use ground tho.

Comment: It is not that it is **impossible** to (a) combine DC & AC power in one circuit or (b) use a ground wire as an "extra" wire. It is that these things go against the electrical code *for a bunch of reasons, including **life safety**.*

Comment: In Europe, in many homes, ground is tied to the metal patress boxes throughout the house.  I'm still not seeing any health risk from using ground. What i would expect is horrible noise, and static buildup. I am really grateful for your input @manassehkatz

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: this is a dumb idea, primarily because 3C+E cable is wayyyy expensive, and it's a lot cheaper to just use 2C+E alongside 2C, which then allows for thicker wires / more current on the 24v circuit.

Thanks to (most of) you all for the informed answers and comments.